# move event was interrupted by another touch event

Tags: android

I am using "adb shell input swipe " to swipe. But in scrolling if i touch the screen, it will stop. 
Any way to avoid this?

And i see the "input swipe" code in Input.java, it use several move events to realize. And I add some log, injectMotionEvent may return false when interrupted. The reason is inject failed. what does this mean?

Comment: Could you include the exact adb command that you use, what you expect it to do, and what it actually does please?

Comment: such as " adb shell input swipe 200 300 200 1000 1000 ", in scrolling touch screen, the scroll stopped. i wanna it not stop. I also wanna what cause it.